# No branches exist in new GitLab project

Tags: git, gitlab

I recently setup a new GitLab CE install for use in my office and every time I create a new project from the web UI it creates it completely empty, without any branches, including master. When a project has a master branch, I can go to commits > branches to create a new one. But the "Files" and "Commits" tabs don't exist in a completely virgin project.

The only way I've found to solve this is clone the repo locally, create a master branch, and then push that to the GitLab server.

But it would be *really* nice if it would just automatically create a master branch with no files (or maybe a .gitignore and README) by default, like GitHub does.

Is there a way to make it do this in GitLab?

I'm running the latest CE from the omnibus installer on CentOS 6.

Comment: Did you found a solution to that issue? I am sitting in front of gitlab the first time and can't find any option in my new project to see branches or more important to unprotect my master branch.

Answer (score 5):

In the current GitLab CE (version 8) empty projects promt to add a REAMDE.md:

[image: Create new file in empty GitLab repository]

which includes the following URL (with `domain`, `group`, `project` of my project) for **adding README**:

```
https://domain.com/group/project/new/master?file_name=README.md
```

The `master` branch can be unprotected only after the branch is created.